# Continuous mappings preserve almost everywhere convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Given a sequence of maps $(f_n)$ that converges almost everywhere to $f$ and a continuous map $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is it true that $g(f_n)\rightarrow g(f)$ almost everywhere? I think this should be true because [continuous maps preserve convergent sequences](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Mappings_preserve_Convergent_Sequences).

Comment: Consider $g \circ f_n$ outside the null set where the $f_n$ do **not** converge to $f$.

Comment: So outside the $\mu$-null set, there is pointwise convergence. Hence, $g\circ f_n$ also convergence pointwise outside of the same null set. So, there is a.e. convergence